# If promise does not return value

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a promise that returns a function, the function does have its own error handling but sometimes for some reason this gets missed (need to explore this later).

I want to add a fallback that if the promise fails/null then return another function.

```
if (completedForm.isValid()) {
   return formDataQueue.push(formJson, this.company).then(function () {
      return self.trySync();
   });
}
```

`Return self.trySync():` needs a error handler to assume it's not there as if it was commented out. My attempt does not seem to work.

```
if (completedForm.isValid()) {
   return formDataQueue.push(formJson, this.company).then(function () {
      //return self.trySync();
   }, function(error) {
      router.navigate('home');
   });
}
```

Comment: If `trySync` doesn't return a promise, you can test for that, but if it returns a promise that never resolves, it's going to be harder

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*assume it's not there as if it was commented out*". What would cause it to "not be there"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [difference between `.then(…).catch(…)` and `.then(…, …)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572).

To handle errors from `trySync()` (and only from there), you want to use

```
if (completedForm.isValid()) {
    return formDataQueue.push(formJson, this.company).then(function () {
        return self.trySync().catch(function(error) {
            router.navigate('home');
        });
    });
}
```